# MATLAB division... should 29/128 return 0?

Tags: matlab, division, integer-division

I really don't think this is a precision problem, the answer should be about 0.226. Here's the exact code:

```
val = I(i,j)
bucketSize    
pos = val / bucketSize
```

`I` is just a matrix I'm taking values from. Here is the output from MATLAB:

```
val =

   29

bucketSize =

   128

pos =

   0
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My guess would be that your matrix `I` is pixel data loaded from an [image file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html), which will have values that are typically [unsigned 8-bit integers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html). As already mentioned, converting both integer values to a [double precision](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) value will ensure that MATLAB performs floating point division instead of integer division (which will round off the result).

Converting one value to [double precision](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) is insufficient:

> For all binary operations in which one operand is an array of integer
>   data type (except 64-bit integers) and the other is a scalar double,
>   MATLAB computes the operation using elementwise double-precision
>   arithmetic, and then converts the result back to the original integer
>   data type.

If you'd like to find out more about the different numeric data types in MATLAB, you can check out [this documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html).

Answer (score 12):

try:

```
double(val)/double(bucketSize)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it, the problem is that my matrix for some reason contained uint8's, not doubles. Just changed val=I(i,j) to val=double( I(i,j) ) and all is well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These variables are probably ints rather than doubles or longs. Does 1/2 return .5? Do other operations work?

Comment: Yes. For instance, 29/128 results in the correct answer. I was under the impression Matlab was typeless? How do I set the variables to be doubles?